# Reading (input) a file whose name is created with a label

Tags: expansion, input, labels

I don't want to get into the details of why I want to do this, but I would like to:

- create a new counter called `filenumber`;
- create a file whose filename is `\jobname\thefilenumber.txt` and write to it;
- read (input) the content from that file.

Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{newfile}

\newcounter{filenumber}
\newoutputstream{outputfile}

\newcommand{\createoutputfile}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{filenumber}\label{#1}

  \openoutputfile{\jobname\thefilenumber.txt}{outputfile}
  \addtostream{outputfile}{#2}
  \closeoutputstream{outputfile}
}


\begin{document}

\createoutputfile{timmyfile}{Hello world!}

Timmy, what would you like to tell the world?

Timmy's answer has been written to:\\
{\ttfamily \jobname\ref{timmyfile}.txt}

Timmy's answer: \input{\jobname1.txt}

%% The following does not work
\makeatletter
%{\@@input \jobname\ref{timmyfile}.txt}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

I know that `\input` isn't expandable, but even using TeX's `\@@input`, I can't manage to input the file if I try to construct the filename using the label created earlier. Uncommenting the `\@@input` line actually has the perverse effect of creating 50 identical files (numbered from 1 to 50) containing "Hello world!".

If I use `\include` instead of `\input` to trace what is happening, the .aux file contains the following:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{timmyfile}{{1}{1}}
\@input{stackexchange_read_filename_from_ref1\hbox {}.txt.aux}
```

It seems that the reference is being expanded to `1\hbox {}`.

Could this be the issue? How can I fix this and input a file whose filename is created using a label in such a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an expandable version of `\ref`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{newfile}

\newcounter{filenumber}
\newoutputstream{outputfile}

\newcommand{\createoutputfile}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{filenumber}%
  \label{THISFILE#1}%
  \openoutputfile{\jobname\thefilenumber.txt}{outputfile}
  \addtostream{outputfile}{#2}
  \closeoutputstream{outputfile}
}
\newcommand{\readfile}[1]{%
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname\getrefnumber{THISFILE#1}.txt}{}{``RERUN''}%
}

\begin{document}

\createoutputfile{timmyfile}{Hello world!}

Timmy, what would you like to tell the world?

Timmy's answer: \readfile{timmyfile}

\end{document}
```

When the cross-reference is not solved, so the file is not found, `”RERUN”` is printed.

Comment: There is an extra } in your code at line `\openoutputfile{\jobname\thefilenumber}.txt}{outputfile}`

I believe you are a cyborg. ;)